# How to make camera same speed as player

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making an endless runner on LibGDX with Box2d. I want to make the camera and player move at the same speed so while everything's fine, the player is in the center of the screen. I don't want it to just always make the player the center though, since I want the player to be left behind by the camera if the player gets stuck (ex. behind a crate). With that, I was thinking that I could translate the camera with the same default velocity that the player has. Doesn't work though. Help?

render() (with the camera update):

```
dx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //stage.getCamera().translate(Constants.DEFAULT_VELOCITY / Constants.PIXELS_TO_BOX, 0, 0);
    //the commented function call above was what I was thinking; doesnt work
    stage.getCamera().position.x = player.getX();
    batcher.begin();
    batcher.draw(AssetLoader.background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batcher.end();

    stage.draw();

    batcher.begin();
    debugRenderer.render(gameWorld.getWorld(), debugMatrix);
    batcher.end();
```

part of Player:

```
public Player(Texture texture, float x, float y, World world) {
    this.texture = texture;
    setWidth(texture.getWidth()); //pixels
    setHeight(texture.getHeight()); //pixels
    setPosition((x + getWidth()/2), y + (getHeight()/2)); //pixels
    setName("player");

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(x / Constants.PIXELS_TO_BOX, y / Constants.PIXELS_TO_BOX); //meters

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(texture.getWidth()/2 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_BOX , texture.getHeight()/2 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_BOX); //meters

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;

    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    body.setFixedRotation(true);
    shape.dispose();    

    body.setUserData(this);
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(Constants.DEFAULT_VELOCITY, body.getLinearVelocity().y));
    //what I use to set velocity
    if (hasJumped) {
        jump();
        hasJumped = false;
        Gdx.app.log("player", "jumped");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to multiply velocity by delta time to get translation.

Comment: In this situations, I fix the camera and move the world.